# Tkinter command function call

Tags: python, tkinter, button, command, call

I am new with python ,
And since i started python the command call in Tkinter never works for me
I have tried all the ways and i took of the brakets off but it doesn't work still
i have seen the related topics here but they didn't work for me
here is a simple code that i have tried noting that when i  clic the button nothing happens so where is the problem coming from?

```
from tkinter import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    compile_button=Button(root,text="Compiler",command=root.quit)
    compile_button.pack()
```

Comment: It works fine by adding `root.mainloop()` after `compile_button.pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `root.mainloop()` at the end of your `__main__`. So the GUI starts working. For further info check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29158220/11101156).
2. You can also use `root.destroy` method.

The whole code:

```
from tkinter import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    compile_button=Button(root,text="Compiler", command=root.quit)
    compile_button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mmm. What version of Tkinter are you using? Are you executing the python file from command line or in some IDE? Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: I am using python ide

Comment: Tkinter version 8.6

Comment: No it just doesn't happen anything